# Wordpress `wp_mail` fails with an HTTP error 500

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress 3.0.1 on Windows 2003 32-bit running PHP 5.x with fastcgi on IIS6.

I am using the *Contact Form 7* plugin for WordPress, and getting an HTTP 500 error on submit.  I am also getting HTTP 500 errors sending the test mail using the *Configure-Smtp* plugin.  I've narrowed it down to the `wp_mail` line in both cases.

I can create a .php page in the same website and send an email using the php mail function, so I'm pretty sure PHP, IIS, and SMTP are all functioning.

Firebug does not give me much in the way of useful info - I can paste the post and response headers if it would help.

Comment: Sounds like an issue sending mail, not `Contact Form 7`.

Comment: Not sure where you get "issue sending mail" when the server, IIS, and PHP are all able to send mail.  The issue is Contact Form 7 isn't sending mail.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-uploading the wp-admin and wp-includes folders from a fresh install of WordPress. May be you're missing some files!